# Crawling with Apache Nutch 1.9 using Java code

Tags: java, nutch

We have developed a data processing pipeline which crawls web data given a set of configured URLs using Apache Nutch 1.4. The pipeline subsequently applies a series of mapreduce tasks to process the web data and finally it is indexed into Solr. We use both pre-configured hadoop cluster as well as Amazon EMR.

This application was developed 3 years ago and have not been used for almost a year. When we tried running it now with the latest EMR release (4.x) it failed. I suppose, Apache Nutch 1.4 is not supported anymore as it uses older hadoop version (1.x). So we decided to upgrade to Nutch 1.9. However, we found that Nutch 1.9 does not have the Crawl class (org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl) anymore that we were using to in 1.4 version to crawl from Java code. Checking the docs I found that the suggested approach is to use the script **bin/crawl**.

However, per me calling a script from java code does not seem too good an approach as we are invoking an external process that gives us much less control.
So how do I proceed? Write my own version of org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl or is there some other class which I am missing here?

My requirement is simple. I want to invoke the Nutch API 1.9 or above from Java code.

Comment: You can see how it's done in this GitHub repository: https://github.com/yegor256/nutch-in-java It demonstrates how Nutch can be used from the Java code, not from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is a REST API being developed for Nutch 1.X - https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch_1.X_RESTAPI

There is no direct crawl api like the one you are talking about, but you could try invoking the jobs using the REST endpoints to see if they fit your use case.